# Wrap event emitter and listener in a function

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

I am using the [python-shell](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell) library for my express Node JS program to communication with a python program.

There is a python wrapper in that library that uses IPC to communicate. I am trying to wrap the emitter and listener in a function, or have the emitter return a value through callback or async await.

I couldn't find any example online on how to wrap event emitters + listeners in a function.

My JS code

```
var app = require("express")();
const PythonShell = require('python-shell').PythonShell;
const path = require('path');
app.listen(8000, function () {
   console.log('Example app listening on port 8000!');
});

const data = path.join(__dirname, '.') + '/start.py';
var pyshell = new PythonShell(data);

pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
   console.log(message)

});

pyshell.send("hello")
```

My python code

```
import sys

def main():
    while True:
        command = sys.stdin.readline()
        command = command.split('\n')[0]
        if command == "hello":
            sys.stdout.write("You said hello!\n")
        elif command == "goodbye":
            sys.stdout.write("You said goodbye!\n")
        else:
            sys.stdout.write("Sorry, I didn't understand that.\n")
        sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Looking forward to your help. I understand the concept of event emitters + listeners. In my case I have only one listening function.

Comment: I don't fully understand what is the desired result. If you could tell why you want to wrap them that would help

Comment: @Eduard I have a function, let's say, calculator function in node js. whereas i have the sub functions of add(), subtract(), multiply(), divide() in python. So I need to used async await to get the values. But the library offers only event emitters.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the callback in a promise and await its fulfillment. Something like this:

```
function getMessage(pyshell) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pyshell.on('message', message => {
            resolve(message);
        });
        pyshell.on('error', err => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}

(async () => {
    // ...
    const pyshell = new PythonShell(data);
    pyshell.send("hello");
    const message = await getMessage(pyshell);
    console.log(`awaited message: ${message}`)
})();
```

Comment: running `getMessage` two times will register two listeners because with this approach you don't have the way to detach listeners after the message is received.

And imagine another case, where you send 2 messages at the same time, which of the listeners will fire first? This is a concurrency problem.

Comment: Yep that's true of course.

Comment: @eol This is the best answer I could find as of now. But possible EventEmitter memory leak detected in addition to the concurrency issue